# asterisk and Plus definition issue

Tags: regex

I start reading Regex, and in article i find these :

```
The asterisk or star tells the engine to attempt to match the preceding token zero or more times.
```

and

```
The plus tells the engine to attempt to match the preceding token once or more
```

i googled about meaning of above sentences, but i really can not understand what is meant by the term `preceding token once or more` and `preceding token zero or more times`, some one can explain these by an example? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `f+`, here the preceding token is `f`, ie the pattern before `+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"preceding token" means just that, the preceding token.

The effect the `*` or `+` has is the rest of the sentence:

- `*` means that the preceding token, whatever that may be, can be matched zero or more times
- `+` means that the preceding token, whatever that may be, can be matched one or more times

A "token" here is one unit of pattern, it can be any of the following examples + many more:

- A single character: `A+` matches one or more `A`s, and `A*` matches zero or more `A`s, like `AAAAA`
- A character class: `\d+` matches a digit, one ore more times, like `123450`
- A character set: `[a-f]+` matches any letter from `a` to `f`, one or more times, like `afdbe`
- A group: `(test)+` matches the text `test` one or more times, like `testtesttest`

"zero or ..." means that the pattern may also match nothing, here is an example pattern: `123450*6`, this will match the following examples:

- `1234506` <-- here the `0` occurs once (which is more than zero)
- `123450006` <-- here it occurs three times (also more than zero)
- `123456` <-- here it occurs zero times, which is legal if you use the `*`, but not if the pattern had been `123450+6`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, i got it, +1 for your explanation.