# List lines with start and end with vowels

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I need to list all lines which start and end with vowels characters (aeiou) in file.txt.

```
grep -i '^[aeiou]*[aeiou]' file.txt
```

My understanding is

```
-i = search with case insensitive
^[aeiou] = search at start of each line
*[aeiou] = search at end of line
```

One of the outputs which do not satisfy these conditions is

> Uabcdh

The above word starts with "u" but does not end with [aeiou]

whereas I have tried below as an alternative

```
grep -i '^[aeiou]' file.txt | grep -i '[aeiou]$'
```

and "**Uabcdh**" does not come as an output with the above command.

What is wrong with the first command?

Comment: Unless you're using a weird form of regular expressions, your understanding is wrong. The `*` is combined with the previous pattern to say "0 or more occurences". Instead you probably want this pattern: `^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$`.

Comment: The `^` alone means "start of line", `$` alone means "end of line", `*` means "previous pattern 0 or more times". Your pattern basically said this: "From the start of the line, 0 or more vowels followed by a vowel". Since you didn't use `$`, it did not say "at the end of the line". `.*` in my comment above means "any character 0 or more times".

Comment: Additionally, you probably want to include the letter `y` as well.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen isn't this more suited as an answer than comments?

Comment: @Prajwal If I weren't just typing on my phone, sure. If you want to "hijack" my comment and turn it into a full answer, please go ahead, I don't mind.

Comment: here you go `^[aeiou](?:.*[aeiou])?$`

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen
got it now. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Use the pattern provided by @sln, it covers single lines only containing 1 vowel as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asterisk and Plus definition issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482184/asterisk-and-plus-definition-issue)

Answer (score 1):

You do miss a $ at the end to say its end of line. And a dot before the star to give any characters.

```
grep -i '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$'
```

Edit to handle one character, make last section optional

```
grep -i -E '^[aeiou](.*[aeiou])?$'
```

Comment: This adds a restriction that file name must be at least of two character to match, i.e it will not match `a.txt` whereas as per rules it should match,

Answer (score 1):

The original `^[aeiou]*[aeiou]` POSIX BRE pattern matches the start of the line with `^`, then matches 0 or more (as `*` is a quantifier that matches 0 or more occurrences of the modified subpattern) `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` or `u` chars, and then matches any one of these chars. So, it matches lines like `abc` or `a` or `aei=A-O(UB)C D/+1` and so on.

What you want is

```
grep -i '^[aeiou]\(.*[aeiou]\)\{1,0\}$' file.txt # POSIX BRE
grep -i -E '^[aeiou](.*[aeiou])?$' file.txt      # POSIX ERE
grep -i -P '^[aeiou](?:.*[aeiou])?$' file.txt    # PCRE
```

With the PCRE one, the non-capturing group is used, `(?:...)`, that is not available in the former two regex flavors.

All three match (POSIX ERE regex explanation):

- `^` - start of line
- `[aeiou]` - one of the specified chars
- `(.*[aeiou])?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `.*`  - any 0+ chars
  - `[aeiou]` - one of the specified chars
- `$` - end of line.